# jQuery hide(), ease to coordinates

Tags: jquery, hide, coordinates

Anyone ever found a jQuery hide() easing function that can go to certain X & Y coordinates? To make it look like it's being thrown? Because the default hide("slow") will go to the top left (I believe), not to a certain position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combine two animations together - hide, which changes height and width to 0, and animate change of marginLeft and marginRight to desired value, or maybe make whole new animation, like.

[Example one](http://jsfiddle.net/Jacek_FH/wfqHb/):

HTML:

```
<img id='book' src="http://media.thelogomix.com/preset_9/stack.jpg" />
```

Javascript:

```
$('#book').toggle(function(){
    $(this).animate({
        height: '100',
        marginLeft: '+=300',
        marginTop: '+=300',
    }, 500, function() {
    });
}, function(){
    $(this).animate({
        height: '400',
        marginLeft: '-=300',
        marginTop: '-=300',
    }, 500, function() {
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
#book {
    position: absolute;
}
```

[Another example](http://jsfiddle.net/Jacek_FH/wfqHb/1/)

Comment: there is a checkmark or up arrow on the left to express Your gratitude ;)